# Python - Adding jobs to multiprocessing pool part by part

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

We are currently adding too many jobs to the `pool` and start executing them in multiprocesses. However, we are facing a memory problem due to the high number of optimization parameters and a very big dataset. Dataset is `110 MB` before calculations (it grows bigger) and we currently use over 3 million possible parameter combinations. This consumes all available `RAM` (We have 128 GB RAM) and processes stop at some level.

Is it possible to add the jobs to the pool part by part so the executed jobs are deleted from RAM? One other option is to check the pool constantly and if there is nothing in the pool add, say, 1000 new jobs.

Is this possible?

This is how we add jobs to the pool and execute them:

```
def loop(self, parameters, parameter_index, pool, execute_method):
    parameter = list(parameters.values())[parameter_index]

    value = parameter["start_value"]

    temp_value = Decimal(str(value))
    while temp_value <= Decimal(str(parameter["end_value"])):
        parameter["current_loop_value"] = value
        value += parameter["step_size"]
        temp_value = temp_value + Decimal(str(parameter["step_size"]))

        if parameter_index + 1 < len(parameters):
            self.loop(parameters, parameter_index + 1, pool, execute_method)
            continue

        self.thread_count += 1

        current_parameter = copy.deepcopy(parameters)
        current_parameter["index"] = self.thread_count
        execute_method(pool, current_parameter)

        if self.thread_count % self.thread_count_for_memory_check == 0:
            while True:
                if psutil.virtual_memory().percent < self.memory_leak_threshold:
                    break
                time.sleep(self.memory_leak_sleep_time)
                print("sleeping for {} seconds.... ".format(self.memory_leak_sleep_time), psutil.virtual_memory())

def execute_in_pool(self, pool, parameters):
    pool.apply_async(self.execute_strategy, args=(self.dataset_dict, parameters, self.thread_count),
                     callback=self.thread_callback)
```

Comment: Worth a read, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681322/how-to-add-tasks-to-a-pool-in-a-task-executed-by-the-same-pool

Comment: @Ajay2588 Already read that. Not the same problem but might help. Thanks for the link.